# How to have the column letters in a formula automatically increment

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a table with multiple tabs. 
On Tab "Reviewers", I have the reviewers' names in column A, and the items (documents) being reviewed in columns G through AG.
Each column contains the number of comments each reviewer made on each document.
On Tab "Review Metrics", I have the documents in Column A, and want to have the cumulative metrics in the subsequent columns.
So, to count the number of comments for the document in Column G of "Reviewers", I have the following:

```
 =COUNTIF(Reviewers!G$2:Reviewers!G$223, ">0")
```

What I want to avoid is having to go through the following rows incrementing G to H to I ... to AG. Especially as I have 6 columns (so far) which need to have similar edits:

- `=COUNTBLANK(Reviewers!$G$2:Reviewers!G$223)`,
- `=SUMIFS(Reviewers!G$2:G$223, Reviewers!$B$2:$B$223, $M$3)`,
- etc.

I've tried concatenation, indirect, address, and every other combination I can think of, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic ranges with the `OFFSET` function. 
For example, `OFFSET(Reviewers!$A$1, 1, 6, 222, 1)` evaluates to `Reviewers!G$2:Reviewers!G$223`,
because `Reviewers!G$2` is one row down and six columns to the right of `Reviewers!$A$1`. 
Similarly, `OFFSET(Reviewers!$A$1, 1, 7, 222, 1)` is `Reviewers!H$2:Reviewers!H$223`. 
Just use `OFFSET` with the third parameter set to `ROW()` plus or minus the appropriate constant.